# Find a value & key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, I need to find if one of the values in array one matches one of the values in array two, a multi-dimensional array.  I also need to check that the value from array one is in a specific key in array two, the "principal" key as the "authority" key may also hold this value.

here is array one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
```

and array two [actually slightly truncated for readability]:

```
Array
(
    [modAccessResourceGroup] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 0
                            [authority] => 9999
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [load] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 2
                            [authority] => 10
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [add_children] => 1
                                    [create] => 1
                                    [copy] => 1
                                    [delete] => 1
                                    [list] => 1
                                    [load] => 1
                                    [move] => 1
                                    [publish] => 1
                                    [remove] => 1
                                    [save] => 1
                                    [steal_lock] => 1
                                    [undelete] => 1
                                    [unpublish] => 1
                                    [view] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    .... truncated ....

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 16
                            [authority] => 9999
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [load] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 0
                            [authority] => 9999
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [load] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 1
                            [authority] => 9999
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [add_children] => 1
                                    [create] => 1
                                    [copy] => 1
                                    [delete] => 1
                                    [list] => 1
                                    [load] => 1
                                    [move] => 1
                                    [publish] => 1
                                    [remove] => 1
                                    [save] => 1
                                    [steal_lock] => 1
                                    [undelete] => 1
                                    [unpublish] => 1
                                    [view] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [principal] => 22
                            [authority] => 9999
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [add_children] => 1
                                    [create] => 1
                                    [copy] => 1
                                    [delete] => 1
                                    [list] => 1
                                    [load] => 1
                                    [move] => 1
                                    [publish] => 1
                                    [remove] => 1
                                    [save] => 1
                                    [steal_lock] => 1
                                    [undelete] => 1
                                    [unpublish] => 1
                                    [view] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I was using a series of foreach(){foreach(){foreach(){}}} but it seemed very messy and inefficient. Having some trouble getting my head around this. Any ideas?

Comment: So what would array one match in your example?

Comment: I need to find if any of the values in array one match any of the 'principal' values in array two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function should do the trick:

```
$values = array(17, 6, 3, 2, 5);

function find($array, &$values) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            find($element, $values);
        }

        elseif ($key == 'principal') {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                if ($element == $value) {
                    echo 'Found' . PHP_EOL;
                    // Do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

find($array, $values);
```

Comment: I will certainly try, but I need to keep it as light as possible ~ the code could conceivably be executed up to 2000 times per request. i.e. searching recursively through 2000+ array per request.

Comment: Recursion is usually pretty fast, but if you can, you might want to try saving the principal values in a separate single-dimensional array so you can use the in_array function to check if a value is in there. If that's all you need, this would be really fast.

Comment: As Revent suggested [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is a good solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind. First, in situations like this, I will usually create a separate array with just the principal values so that I can loop over the first array and just use a simple `in_array()` check. Secondly, if you don't want to do that, you could do something using the [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function or some of the recursive examples in [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to go through your second array.

Comment: I've been trying to use, in_array($memberof, $value, true) where $memberof is array one and the $value are the deepest nested arrays, but for some reason it does not work? Does in_array only work on strings if you try to pass an array as the needle?

Comment: Ya, I have only used it for single-dimensional arrays - I don't think it's built to do complex searches. That's why a recursive array search is needed here.

Comment: In regards to: in_array($memberof, $value, true) where $memberof is array one and the $value are the deepest nested arrays - it *should* work using $memberof as the needle (assuming PHP 4.2 or later), but you might try setting the third value to false so that it won't do the strict type matching and will match 1 with '1'. I'd have to see your code to know if there was some other reason why it doesn't work.